# bluetooth classic nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to read from a bluetooth classic device using NativeScript.
I can list paired devices but when I try to connect :

```
tmp=device_to_connect.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(my_UUID);
tmp.connect()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

I know that could possibly be solved using (Java code):

```
 mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) device_to_connect.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(device_to_connect,1);
```

I am not sure how to go from there ... considering the fact that I am coding in Javascript....

Comment: Try using https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-bluetooth

Comment: The questions could use a lot more clarification or context. As for the last part - the Java code can be adapted to the following in JavaScript, mind you, context is scarce: `mmSocket = device_to_connect.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", [int.class]).invoke(device_to_connect, 1);`

Comment: @NickIliev I am using Bluetooth classic not Bluetooth LE

Comment: @pkanev I am trying to connect to a HC-06 bluetooth module and I would like to be able to read data coming from it.

Comment: I was actually talking about code.